# How to access the query variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

how can I read the query variable outside the **if** scope and use it further.

```
If (IsPaymentList)
{
            var query = paymentList.GroupBy(
            grp => (grp.GrouByField),
            (GrouByField, paymentListgroup) => new
            {
                Key = GrouByField,
                receiptAmount = paymentListgroup.Sum(fields => fields.PaymentAmount),
                creditAccountnumber = paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.CreditAccountNumber),
                bankAccountName = paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.AccountName),
                bankName = paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.BankName),
                payCurrency = paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.PaymentCurrencyID),
                partnerServiceID = paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.PartnerServiceID),

            });
}
```

Somebody please share your experience.
Thanks

Comment: Not possible if you are use var

Comment: the cleanest solution I can think of is using a named type.

Comment: This has nothing to do with query but basic programming knowledge. Please lookup scope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @PoweRoy I'm sure the OP would know how to move a normal variable to the outside of the scope. The problem here is that the variable is implicitly typed to an anonymous type. So you can't simply move the declaration while keeping the initialization in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the query variable as of type
`IQueryable<IGrouping<typeOfKey,typeOfSelect>> query = null;`
outside the if and set it to null where the typeOfKey is the type of the grp.GrouByField property. Instead of selecting an anonymous type you have to create a new class that has the properties as needed like this:

```
public class NewClass
{
     public int Key {get;set;}
     public decimal ReceiptAmount {get;set;}
     //add all the properties here

     public NewClass(string key,decimal recieptAmount)
     {
          //and add constructor for all the needed properties
     }
}
```

After you create the class set the query to the generic type

```
//i used int for your grp.GrouByField type
IQueryable<IGrouping<int,NewClass>> query = null;
if(IsPaymentList)
{
    query = paymentList.GroupBy(
            grp => (grp.GrouByField),
            (GrouByField, paymentListgroup) => 
            new NewClass(GrouByField, 
            paymentListgroup.Sum(fields => fields.PaymentAmount), 
            paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.CreditAccountNumber), 
            paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.AccountName), 
            paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.BankName), 
            paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.PaymentCurrencyID), 
            paymentListgroup.Max(fields => fields.PartnerServiceID)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to move the query-variable out of the context of the if-statement.

This is an example on how you do that with an integer list:

```
var list = new [] { 10, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 };

var condition = false;

IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,int>> query;

if(condition)
{
    query = list.GroupBy(x => x);
}
```

Then I can continue query the `query`variable like this after the if-statement if I so like:

`query.Take(2)`

The problem is here that you want to use the `query` variable outside of the scope that you are creating it.

Consider the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = 10;

    {
        var y = 20;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(x+y);
}
```

This wont compile because `y` is in another scope than `x`, you solve this by moving the decleration of `y` outside of that scope. Like this:

```
var x = 10;
int y;
{
    y = 20;
}

Console.WriteLine(x+y);
```

You can't use `var` when declaring `y` in this case because that would imply that you are also telling the compiler what kind of type it is. And you are not. So writing `var y;` wouldn't make any sense, but `var y = 10;` does because now the compiler knows that this is in fact an integer.

Comment: Now you lost the static type of `query`

Comment: @CodeInChaos, better like that?